# Python MySQL. How to INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE from dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am updating a MySQL database table from a Python dictionary where the keys are the database fields. I have an insert statement that works but what I really need is INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
Here is the insert statement:

```
for d in r.json()['mydict'].items():  
    d = d[1] #the dictionary is the 2nd element in the tuple
    placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(d))
    columns = ', '.join(d.keys())
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % ("my_table", columns, placeholders) 
    c = create_connection() #from function create tables
    cur = c[0] #function returns cursor
    db = c[1] #function returns db
    cur.execute(sql, list(d.values()))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: need more information , INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, give us some example through data

Comment: @ETL_Devs Just a normal dictionary with key/value pairs. The keys are the database table's columns and the values are inserted or updated a new or existing row. An example from W3 is: thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
} 'brand' is the column header and 'Ford' is the inserted or updated value.